# Is Broccoli Rob dead?

Tags: continuity, the-office

Broccoli Rob dies in
[season 7](http://officequotes.net/no7-05.php) of [*The Office*](http://imdb.com/title/tt0386676):

```
Andy:    Ooh, says here Dan Becker fell off the side of Kilimanjaro in a
         climbing accident. It appears Dan's Sherpa survived to tell the tale -
         Oh, my God!
Phyllis: What? Is Dan okay?
Andy:    No, he died. It's Broccoli Rob.
```

but then he texts Andy in
[season 8](http://officequotes.net/no8-05.php):

```
Andy: I just got a text from Broccoli Rob - "Boo!" Scared me.
```

and he is seen again in
[season 9](http://officequotes.net/no9-05.php),
played by Stephen Colbert:

```
Broccoli Rob: I just-- I just started yappin’ about the old days, and I guess
              the wine coolers were flowing, and, you know, somehow things just
              got hinky.
```

So, what happened here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you simply misunderstood the quote. Here's the full quote:

> Andy: [reading Cornell magazine] Whoa. Libby Dirketts got married. Big Red mazel tov to the Libster. Ooh, says here Dan Becker fell off the side of Kilimanjaro in a climbing accident. It appears Dan's Sherpa survived to tell the tale-Oh, my God!
>
> Phyllis: What? Is Dan okay?
>
> Andy: No, he died. It's Broccoli Rob. You know this guy; I showed you his picture on Facebook.
>
> Phyllis: Yes.
>
> Andy: "Some Vermont-based alums can hear 'Broccoli' Rob Blatt, '96, in the state milk lobby's new milk awareness song, 'Calci-YUM!', featuring Phish's Trey Anastasio. Says Broccoli, 'Trey and I had a ton of fun in the studio, and I think you can hear it in the song.'"
>
> Phyllis: Oh, that's great news for your friend.
>
> Andy: Yeah, yeah, it's great...

"He died" refers to Dan. "Oh my god!" refers to the *next story* about Broccoli Rob, which is deemed more important for comedic effects.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I feel his delivery of these lines was poor, adding to the confusion